# Combinatorial Problem, 30 balls, 3 unique colors, 10 of each color. We pick 20, probability of getting 3 unique colors?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> There are $10$ balls each of $3$ colors ($30$ balls total). We pick $20$ balls. What is the probability that $20$ balls represent $3$ unique colors?

My answer: $\dfrac{27\choose{17}}{30\choose{20}} = 0.2808$

This is obviously wrong, because this number should be greater than $0.5$ (intuitively), as the probability of picking balls with $2$ unique colors will obviously be less than $0.5$, and the probability of picking balls with $1$ unique color is obviously $0$.

Explanation: I pick $3$ balls, $1$ each of $3$ unique colors and then pick the remaining $20 - 3 = 17$ balls out of $30 - 3 = 27$ balls.

Why is the answer wrong? What will be the correct answer?

Comment: Imagine if you will that the box had 30 balls, 3 unique colors, 10 of each color, and for each color exactly one of the balls is metal while all others are rubber.  The probability $\binom{27}{17}/\binom{30}{20}$ is the probability that among the $20$ balls selected, all three of the metal balls are chosen.  "*I pick 3 balls each of 3 unique colors and then pick...*"  In doing so you accidentally treated those three balls as being special.

Comment: As for a correct approach... consider calculating the opposite event... that when picking 20 balls we wind up *not* having all three colors present... what would that imply about the ten remaining balls?  Can you calculate the probability of this occurring?  Subtract that away from $1$ to get the probability you were originally after.  As for a generalized approach for if a different number of balls were selected other than $20$, inclusion-exclusion is the way to go.

Comment: Welcome to M.SE! Please check the edit, once approved, to ensure it matches your intention. Here's a MathJax Tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/431789

Comment: $1-3\text{P}_{\text{All balls of one colour are missing}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of questions, I often find myself looking at the opposite event: what is the probability that the twenty balls contain less than three colors? Obviously, since there are ten balls of each color, at least two colors will be represented. There are only three ways to select twenty balls containing two colors only (namely, by choosing one of the three colors not to appear in the selection of twenty balls). We thus find that the probability of selecting two colors equals:

$$\frac{{3 \choose 1}{20 \choose 20}}{30 \choose 20} = \frac{3}{30045015}$$

As such, the probability of all three colors being represented equals:

$$1 - \frac{3}{30045015} \approx 0.99999990015$$